# how to generate hibernate pojos from sqlite db?

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, code-generation, pojo

i have sqlite db. i want to get entities and hbm files for it.
i tried NetBeans it says that table dont have primary keys.

tried DB Importer eclipse plugin: says input contained no data.

Eclipse hibernate tools generates code only for one table for some reason.

it seams its some weird thing with sqlite. beacause i can generate code from other dbs fine.
Please give some ideas, cuz my db has many tables. Maybe someone who did this already could help me?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question.  Can you please provide more background and descriptions of your question.  Code snippets and exceptions are usually good as well.

Comment: thnx for answer. I have a Sqlite database. I want to generate pojos and mapping files for all the tables in db.

Comment: Edit your question with more information.  So you are trying to create data objects that match existing tables so you can read/write them in hibernate?

Comment: but i dont have any more information. I just want some tool to reverese engineer my database and create entities and .hbm

Comment: This link mentions how to get hibernate tools to generate multiple tables: http://www.yuvalararat.com/2008/03/hibernate-auto-generate-hbm-and-java/

Comment: thnx for responce. I allready tried hibernate tools and it generates code only for 1 table for some random reason:(

Comment: To quote from the link I posted: "Multiple table names can be specified using sql wild char (eg: TBL_%)."

Comment: it only works only for one particular table. it ignores all other.

Comment: I turned it into an answer so you can accept it.  Glad it worked @emmma1223.

Comment: Be sure to accept my answer @emmma1223 and +1 if you think it is worthy.  This adds to your score and mine and encourages folks to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The following link mentions how to get hibernate tools to generate multiple tables:

> http://yuvalararat.com/2008/03/hibernate-auto-generate-hbm-and-java

To quote:

> Multiple table names can be specified using sql wild char (eg: TBL_%).